# Get list of groups user hasn't Joined, List of groups user didn't create

Tags: mysql

The user (Ben) has joined group 2 and group 3. How can I write this in a select query... I want to select from groups I haven't joined and groups I didn't create.

```
users_tbl table
user_id username
| 1    | ben
| 2    | betty
| 3    | tim
| 4    | jimmy
| 5    | sammy


user_groups table
user_id         group_id
|      1     |       2
|      1     |       3


group_tbl table
group_id     user_id
|    1    |     5
|    2    |     4
|    3    |     5
```

I am able to get the list of groups I didn't create using this query...

```
SELECT * FROM group_tbl LEFT JOIN users_tbl ON users_tbl.user_id = group_tbl.user_id WHERE group_tbl.user_id != ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

How can I get the list of groups users hasn't joined?

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with PHP or mysqli. I removed those tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you do a `LEFT` join of `group_tbl` to `users_tbl` and return the unmatched rows of `group_tbl`:

```
SELECT g.* 
FROM group_tbl g LEFT JOIN user_groups u 
ON u.group_id = g.group_id AND u.user_id = 1
WHERE u.user_id IS NULL
```

Or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT g.* 
FROM group_tbl g 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM user_groups u 
  WHERE u.group_id = g.group_id AND u.user_id = 1
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=17d7bc0b88e572562b1a907de1794500).
Results:

| group_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |